# Return list of observe Events in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to return the list of observe events in R. For example below is the hardcoded lists of observe events. The numbers here are only 1 and 2. But in real there are more than 100. So I cannot hardcode all. Is there a way to return the list through loop so that 100 observe events are formed (say when n = 100)

```
  list(
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button",rv['rn'][1,])]],{
      print(1)
    }),
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button",rv['rn'][2,])]],{
      print(2)
    })
  )
```

Below is my sample application

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
number_compare <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:100, 10, rep=TRUE)))


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               DTOutput("example_table"))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {



  number_compare <- number_compare %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), button = glue::glue(HTML('<button id="button{rn}" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Ask a question</button>')))

  output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(
      number_compare,
      escape = FALSE
      ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
        'function() {
     Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
        drawCallback= JS(
          'function(settings) {
       Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
  })


  list(
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][1,])]],{
      print(1)
    }),
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][2,])]],{
      print(2)
    })
  )



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example, you can run

```
  lapply(1:100, function(x) {
    id <- paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][x,])
    observeEvent(input[[id]], {print(x)})
  })
```

The `lapply` will loop over the values 1 to 100 and will run observeEvent for each of the different values.

Comment: Perfect Suppose this ````1:100````    is reactive so can i use like below  ````observe({
    lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
      id <- paste0("button",number_compare['rn'][x,])
      observeEvent(input[[id]], {print(x)})
    })
  })````

Comment: Well, `observeEvent` doesn't return a reactive object, it returns an observer reference class object. You can't `observe()` the result of `observerEvent()`

Comment: Well thanks. I have redited my question. Basically the dataframe is reactive and when the user clicks on the button, particular row number (rn) should be printed

Comment: Appreciate if can guide me on how to solve this :)

Comment: You shouldn't fundamentally change a question after it's been answered. If you have a problem other than the one you originally described, then you should open a new question. Again, the example should make clear what you need to have happen so solutions can be tested. What would the `observe()` even do?